# Routing attacks on Peer 2 Peer networks?

Tags: network, attacks, iot, p2p

I've started creating a framework that aims to make anything into an IoT device. In order to stay online, a peer 2 peer layer needs to be implemented. On top of it, common point services will give the network structure and logistical support by offloading computation. Logistical support can come from other peers or common point services which will help the boot strapping process, client updates and information propagation.

My biggest worry is routing attacks but I have a potential solution.
Prior to describing my proposal, let's recall what are routing attacks.

Routing attacks try to disorient peers, by doing so, peer 2 peer' network performance can drop near 0%. Attack methods vary a lot, since there're a lot of implementations of the protocol.
Attackers can impersonate other peers and deceive legitimate consumers.

Proposal on how to avoid performance losses, because of the time consumed in communicating with unworthy peers:

Each peer will communicate only with entities that are willing to exchange/share messages with the other peers. Occasionally, a network participant may require the other party to confirm propagation. This would be done by peer **A** asking peer **B** to retrieve signed messages' hash value generated by peer **C**. This is not the only way propagation's confirmation may take place. Since all peers tend to communicate with each other (if physically possible), peer **A** and **B** may engage in a direct confirmation with one another.

Prior to your conclusion. The network will have multiple fallback channels. I'm okay with experimenting, since what I'm doing is for research purposes.

What are the security concerns of requiring confirmation from other peers on message propagation?

Comment: For those who are interested   https://bitbucket.org/ZarkonesXena/xena
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Or https://github.com/zarkones/XENA for those who rather prefer GitHub platform.